# Using definition of big oh to find estimates

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

In my book Discrete Mathematics 7th Edition by Rosen (Page 214), these two examples of how to find estimates really confused me.

**Find estimate for $(n^2 + 3)$:**

$(n^2 + 3) < 2n^2$ when $n > 2$

How did they get they arrive at $(n^2 + 3) < 2n^2$ specifically the $2n^2$ part?

**Another example that I couldn't understand was:**

Furthermore, $x^2 + 1 ≤ 2x^2$ when $x > 1$.

Hence, $log(x^2+1)≤log(2x^2)=log2+logx^2 =log2+2logx≤3logx$

how did they get  $log2+2logx≤3logx$? Where did this $3logx$ come from?

Comment: They only observe that if $n>2$, then $n^{2}>4>3$. As $n^{2}>3 => n^{2}+n^{2}>n^{2}+3$. The last one I believe will be correct only if x>2, because log is increase function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first example, intuitively we understand that the function $n^{2} + 1$ grows about "as fast" as $n^2$. So you could take any constant, for example take $10n^2$, for this constant ($10$), 
$$n^2 + 1 < 10n^2  \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$$

For the second example, we established that the equality is valid whenever $x > 1$, hence $logx \geq log2$.

Comment: But where did $3logx$ come from and why did we get rid of $2logx$? Sorry, Im still new to this.

Comment: Just add $2logx$ to both sides of the inequality I derived.